# changing "from" field of email to my server email address when relayed through mercury32

Tags: email, email-server

i am using mercury 32 C module. when i send email through relaying, receiver does not get my email address instead he receives relaying email address.

How can i change the relaying email address to be displayed in "from" field.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is really an relaying server, it shouldn't rewrite the from address. If it does, you have to check with your provider why he does this and if he is willing to turn it off. If, on the other hand, you try to use an SMTP server that is meant for another domain (like you try to send mail from@example.com via the GMail SMTP server), the server operator does this on purpose to prevent this and you can't stop it and shouldn't try.

Comment: not really, i m using my Gmail account for relaying ? if u know any reliable relaying server who does not change from field, tell me please ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand this comment. If you are trying to use your GMail account for relaying, it's not going to work.

Comment: ok, i understand, is there any server which doesn't change from field?

Comment: Sorry, it don't know about any "relaying-only" service providers. I usually send mail via the provider who registered the domain for me or run my own mail server in a datacenter.